# Why ionic native plugin not installed properly

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

> Issue in installing native plugin of latest Cli (Ionic) versions

Comment: Please  explain a bit more in the problem

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed npm and is functional. Also, ionic-cordova and its functionality.

Later, follow the docs at [Ionic Native](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native) to install and run the plugin you need.